# My contact page displays an error "No module named "'django"" on heroku but it works fine on my local machine

Tags: python, django, heroku

I can send a message from my local computer to my email just fine but when i deploy my app on heroku i get an error message 'No module named "'django"'. What might be the problem?

Views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def s_contact(request):
    c_form = ContactForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        c_form = ContactForm(data=request.POST)
        if c_form.is_valid():
            email = c_form.cleaned_data['email']
            subject = c_form.cleaned_data['subject']
            message = c_form.cleaned_data['message']   
            send_email(email, subject,message, ['myemail@gmail.com'])
            messages.success(request, f'Your message has been sent!')
            return redirect(seller_home)
    else: 
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        subject = request.POST.get('subject')
        message = request.POST.get('message')

    context = {
        'c_form': c_form
    } 
    return render(request, 'seller/contact.html', context)
```

Forms.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Your Email')
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=150)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)
```

This is the Trace back as requested, hope it helps

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /buyer/contact/
No module named "'django"
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://sakka.herokuapp.com/buyer/contact/
Django Version: 2.0
Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value:    
No module named "'django"
Exception Location: <frozen importlib._bootstrap> in _find_and_load_unlocked, line 953
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.8
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 27 Oct 2019 12:33:56 +0300
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) ...
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) ...
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py in _wrapped_view
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/app/buyer/views.py in b_contact
            send_mail(email, message, subject, ['myemail@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False) ...
```

Kindly assist guys.

Comment: You don't say that/how you have installed django on Heroku, so I'm assuming that is the problem...

Comment: Your local machine has the django installed but not on heroku

Comment: My requirements.txt has django plus my application works fine on heroku only that i cannot send a message. So am guessing django is installed

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for anyone to solve your issue. I would suggest starting by adding a minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and a stack trace (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace).

Comment: @thebjorn kindly tell me what i need to add to make it easy for everyone to solve. On my local machine everything is fine, problem is when i deploy to heroku and i have uploaded the error message. I have uploaded my forms.py and views.py. Just let me know what you need and i will upload it

Comment: Please read the links I provided. You should provide the exact stack trace you're seeing (the one that says "No module named "'django") because it contains a lot of extra information that is useful for diagnosing a problem. Additionally, you should remove all code that is not needed to show your problem, and then (a) include all code necessary for someone else to reproduce your problem, and (b) describe the steps you performed to trigger the error. Note: the fact that it works on your pc and not somewhere else is, by itself, not especially helpful in pinpointing the problem.

Comment: @thebjorn i have uploaded the traceback, kindly look at it and let me know if it is sufficient enough to solve my problem. I am new on this platform so please bear with me when i do not give sufficient information. Thank you.

Comment: I noticed that it says `No module named "'django"` (note the extra and unmatched apostrophe before `django` - I realize that it was included in your question previously, but it was easier to see in the traceback). Maybe check your project for where it is coming from (maybe the `EMAIL_BACKEND` setting?). Also check that you're using Python 3.6.8 and Django 2.0 locally as well as on Heroku. I'm no Heroku expert, so I'm afraid I can't help much more without creating a Heroku project myself to test this. Perhaps someone with more Heroku experience can figure it out without reproducing it first..?

Comment: @thebjorn thank you very much for your effort i will try your solutions